# Convert Numbers to Numbers and Letters in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following number 353711000 and I need to convert it to 35371TH in PHP.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Just for my own curiosity what does 35371TH represent?

Comment: Do you mean you want to display in scientific notation or some kind of custom number notation?

Comment: @lznogood: I would imagine that TH stands for thousands.

Comment: if 35371**1000** is 35371TH, what would 35371**2000** be then?

Answer (score 1):

Without regular expressions:

```
$i = 353711000;
if ($i % 1000 == 0) {
    $s = strval($i / 1000) . 'TH';
} else {
    $s = strval($i);
}
print_r($s);
```

Comment: Good answer, could use `intval($x / 1000) . "TH";` if it won't necessarily end in 0's.